# unable to enter proxy authentication details in synaptic Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: proxy, synaptic

Hi I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04, I work behind a proxy and it has all sorts of complications, authentication, special character in the password. So I used to enter the proxy settings in the synaptic and use.
But in Ubuntu 13.04 - 64 bit, I'm unable to enter the authentication details. I'm able to open up the window but can't enter the details.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, also in 13.04 - 64 bit. 
In Ubuntu 12.10 - 64 bits, on the same machine, it worked.

Anyway, until the problem is solved, you can manually edit its conf file to change proxy parameters for Synaptic.

The file is `/root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf` and you can specify the user and password on the   `httpProxyUser` and 
`httpProxyPass` lines

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you can right click->paste your username and password but im not sure that it will use that proxy anyway.

Comment: right click not working for me.
No cursor is coming.